# Regular Expression With Partial Date Variable

Tags: javascript, regex, string, search

Looking to build a reg expression that does the following:

If given a date-string in the format: a/b/c

I need to build a regular expression that would return true if:

1. month = a
2. date is between x and y (including both limits)
3. year = c

An example:

Date is 3/6/12, 
RegExp return true if:

- month = 3
- day is between 2 and 6 (including limits)
- year = 12

Comment: Just parse the date. Regex can do the job to some extend, but I'd rather not do it in regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:    `\b3/[23456]/12\b`

Unless that above was just an example, then you'll need to clarify what you are after

Comment: I think you could make this nicer by using `[2-6]`.